# A question regarding "present simple"

Tags: present-simple

In [CAGIU](https://books.google.com/books?id=YZAoAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=cambridge%20advanced%20grammar%20in%20use%20unite%201&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q=cambridge%20advanced%20grammar%20in%20use%20unite%201&f=false), we read:

> *"We can use the present simple in phrases such as **It says here, I hear, I gather, I see, I understand** and **They say, (Someone) says, (Someone) tells me** to introduce news that we have heard, read, seen (e.g. on television), or been told."*

Then, it provides the following example which made me ask this question:

> *"Professor Hendricks is at the conference and **I hear** she's an excellent speaker."*

---

If I saw that sentence somewhere else, I would understood it as below:

- I am at the conference and I hear people saying she's an excellent speaker.

Would you please shed some light on this sentence?

Comment: The implication of **I hear X** in that context is "one or more people have told me" or "I have heard one or more people say" or "rumor has it". The present tense indicates that this is a *current* opinion going around and you are spreading the opinion.  **I hear** is also how rumors are spread.  **Pssst. I hear we're getting out early today.**

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo has mistakenly entered the above in the comment field instead of the answer field, I think.

Comment: @P.E. Dant: I wasn't sure of the actual question, so I shed some light as requested.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Well shed.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo The actual question was how to understand that "I hear".

Comment: We cannot conclude that the speaker who says **I hear...** is at that conference. Those words simply report something the speaker has heard recently. It's like saying "I hear this is a good movie".  You don't have to be at the movie theater to say those words.

Comment: @P. E. Dant  fanx.

Comment: Native speakers would not expect that the words *I hear* in the sentence you cite above would indicate that the *hearing* was done at the conference.  It's just another way of saying *I understand from what I've been told at some time in the past*.  In fact, my assumption would be that Professor Hendricks had not yet spoken at the conference which would mean that the *hearing* would have had to have been based on some prior speaking event by Professor Hendricks, so I wouldn't be biased to expect that the person heard that at the conference, as opposed to sometime in the more distant past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the phrase

> **I hear**

in your example

> Professor Hendricks is at the conference and **I hear** she's an excellent speaker.

has the meaning

> I've been told *(perhaps directly by some people)*
>   it is generally known

it usually means you do not have *first hand experience* at hearing her speak.
*When* you "*heard*" about her, was probably before the conference.

Comment: Yes you're right. I forgot this sort of phrases. thanks.